# Ageing Database for age estimation

Tags: dataset, computer-vision, estimation

Does anyone have a working link to the FG-NET ageing database or any other ageing database ? Edit

I have been trying to find on a online source for FG-Net aguing database , MOPRH database and YGA database. I can't seem to find none of them available to download . Does anyone know any other ageing database that i can use? Thankyou. I need an ageing database for a my school thesis as I am building a face recognition system and classifying the faces by age . It would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I expect these links could be useful to you as ageing database, they are all available to download :

[FG-NET ageing database](http://www-prima.inrialpes.fr/FGnet/html/benchmarks.html)

[DATA-VISION-imdb-wiki](https://data.vision.ee.ethz.ch/cvl/rrothe/imdb-wiki/)